# add scrollpanel inside formpanel

Tags: gwt, gxt, formpanel

I want to add a scrollpanel inside a formpanel, the scrollpanel will be having objects of subclass of com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.AdapterField which will be using hide and show methods it could be better if a code snippet or sample code is given...

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the GXT class `AdapterField`, and have tagged the question with GXT, I'm assuming that you mean the GXT class `FormPanel`. `ScrollPanel` is a GWT class, and has no directly corresponding GXT class.

This is because `FormPanel` inherits from `ScrollContainer`, `FormPanel` already has scroll support, you just need to enable it.

```
formPanel.setScrollMode(Scroll.AUTO);
```

or

```
formPanel.setScrollMode(Scroll.AUTOY);
```

will enable vertical scrollbars when the contents consume more space than the container has. See the `ScrollContainer` javadocs for more options on how to deal with scrolling.